# to_sql error: Unknown object type numpy.ndarray during describe

Tags: python, sql-insert, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to insert a dataframe into a sql table and I get the following error

ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Unknown object type numpy.ndarray during describe', 'HY000')

for the following code

```
merged.to_sql('pmg.cwc.EmSignals1', engine, chunksize=1000, 
           if_exists='replace', 
           index=False, 
            dtype ={'monthenddate': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=20),                                                                                                       
           'lastweekday': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=20),
           'item': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=20),
           'sols': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=20),
           'value': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=20)})
```

This is a .head of the dataframe

monthenddate lastweekday   item   sols     value

0   1999-12-31  1999-12-31  value  2W063W1 -0.870225

1   1999-12-31  1999-12-31  value  W1YBRK4  0.078154

2   1999-12-31  1999-12-31  value  X16W902 -0.072731

3   1999-12-31  1999-12-31  value  2X45X4W  1.278582

4   1999-12-31  1999-12-31  value  23X1XWX  0.293649

I have tried a lot, but cannot figure out the cause of the issue.

Comment: Please post the output of `merged.info()`.

Comment: Int64Index: 710719 entries, 0 to 710718
Data columns (total 5 columns):
monthenddate    710719 non-null object
lastweekday     710719 non-null object
item            710719 non-null object
sedols          710719 non-null object
value           710719 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 32.5+ MB
None

Comment: I've added some more code to my answer that you can use to check what are the types of data in your columns.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that for some reason, one of you columns contains numpy arrays. You can verify using `print(merged.info())`.

If that's the case, check the statements, where you assign data to the DataFrame.

Edit: as `print(merged.info())` shows several `object` columns, you still don't know which of them might be numpy arrays. Try this code to dig deeper:

```
for el in merged.iloc[0, :]:
    print('Checking: {:s}.'.format(str(el)))
    print(isinstance(el, np.generic))
    try:
        print(el.shape)
        print('Is a NumPy array.')
    except:
        print('Is not a NumPy array.')
    finally:
        print('-----')
```